# qemu:Nodejs test is failing with tls_setup_handshake:no protocols available::/usr/src/debug/openssl/3.1.0-r0/ssl/statem/statem_lib.c:104 on Qemu

Tags: ssl, nodejs, openssl

I have tried to run nodejs tests on qemu target but parallel/test-tls-getprotocol is failing with below error

=== release test-tls-getprotocol ===
Path: parallel/test-tls-getprotocol
node:events:491
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

Error: C0B7F0CB5B7F0000:error:0A0000BF:SSL routines:tls_setup_handshake:no protocols available:/usr/src/debug/openssl/3.1.0-r:

```
at TLSSocket._start (node:_tls_wrap:980:16)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1479:10)
```

Emitted 'error' event on TLSSocket instance at:

```
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
```

library: 'SSL routines',

reason: 'no protocols available',

code: 'ERR_SSL_NO_PROTOCOLS_AVAILABLE'
}

Node.js v18.14.2
Command: /usr/bin/node /usr/lib/nodejs/ptest/test/parallel/test-tls-getprotocol.js

I have tried suggestions https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/default-to-tls-v1-2-in-all-tls-libraries-in-20-04-lts/12464/8 but that did not work for me

Any one can help on it what I am missing here